# how to convert text to number

Tags: math, formula

i have list of data that contain name and value , and i want to convert the text with number , 
i have tried to convert the text to hexa and hexa to number but here is the problem ,
when the text is long the number is also to big

for example:

`text = "SERVICE_SUM_EXIST"`

after conversion to hexa = `534552564943455f53554d5f4558495354`
and the number
i get `(534552564943455f53554d5f4558495354)16` = (hex value must be maximum length of 32 characters.)10

i want to able to convert long text to maximum 9 digits at most 
my target after that is to take the number and convert it back to text
for example ,`text = "SERVICE_SUM_EXIST"` after calculate it will become `234234323`
and not `314322134215154325143`

so when i will enter this number `234234323`
i will get back the text `SERVICE_SUM_EXIST`

Comment: 9 digits worth of memory can only store a small amount of textual data, depending on your encoding/compression method. You won't be able to store very long strings this way. Maybe what you want is a hash set? Not garunteed to map one-to-one, but it fulfills your key size requirement.

Comment: Andy Lamb so maybe u have an idea how can i store code instead text? because DB table search run faster with numbers and i dont want to use extra table for conversion

Comment: i open to change encoding method if there is one that solve my problem

Comment: Generate a hash from the text and use that to retrieve the text via a lookup. Read up on hash sets though, the lack of a garunteed one-to-one mapping may not fit with your requirement.

Comment: @boazandroid You wrote "DB table search run faster with numbers" - have you considered adding an index to the relevant column in the database?

Comment: yes i had but this solution did not works for me :)